# Add onclick function to a component in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add a click listener to a hyperlink that calls the function from the controller:

**View:**

```
 {
                xtype: 'component',
                autoEl:{
                html: '<a href="#">Forgot password?</a>',
                listeners: {
                    click: 'forgotPassword'
                }}
            }
```

**Controller:**

```
forgotPassword: function () {
    alert('HHHH');
    this.getView().destroy();
}
```

But it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your listeners shouldn't be in the `autoEl` object.
2. Add `element: 'el'` to your listener.

For example:

```
{
  xtype: 'component',
  html: '<a href="#">Forgot password?</a>'
  listeners: {
    element: 'el',
    click: 'forgotPassword'
  }
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1clt